# Hola soy nuevo en codeigniter y me da este fallo gracias

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo esto es Home.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    
    function __contruct()
    {
        parent:: __contruct();
        $this->load->model('getAllUsers');
        
    } 
    
    public function index()
    {
        //$data['nombre'] = 'pablo';
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
    
    public function getUsers()
    {
        $data['nombre'] = 'maria';
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
    
    public function getUsersById($id = null)
    {
        echo "el id es:" .$id;
    }
    
    public function getUrl()
    {
        echo base_url();
    }
    
    // password_hash('123', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
    
    // Y Año actual con 4 digitos, ej 2022
        // m Mes actual en 2 digitos y con 0 en caso del 1 al 9, de 1 a 12
        // d Dia del mes con 2 digitos, y con ceros iniciales, de 01 a 31
        // echo date('Y-m-d');
        
        // H Horario de 24 horas con ceros, de 01 a 23
        // i minutos con ceros iniciales
        // s segundos con ceros iniciales
        // echo date('H-i-s');
        
    
    public function createUser()
    {
        $userData = array(
            'nombre' => 'Pepe', 
            'apellido' => 'Lopez', 
            'img' => 'user.jpg', 
            'email' => 'pepe2gte@gmail.com', 
            'password' => password_hash('123', PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
            'id_country' => 1, 
            'id_state' => 1, 
            'id_role' => 2, // admin    
            'creado_en' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'actualizado_en' => date('H-i-s'),
        );
        
        $this->db->insert('users', $userData);
    }
    
     public function getAllUsers()
    {
        $data = $this->users_model->getUsers();
        
        /* print_r($data);
        
        echo '<br>';
        
        print_r($data[0]->id_usuario);
        
        echo '<br>'; */
        
        print_r($data[1]->id_usuario);
        
        foreach ($data as $users){
            
            echo $users -> id_usuario;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $users -> nombre;
            echo '<br>';
        } 
    }/* 
    public function delete()
    {
        $this->Users_Model->deleteUsers();
        
    }  */
}

?>

y esta otra es el modelo que se conecta 

<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_Model extends CI_Controller {

    function __contruct()
    {
        parent:: __contruct();
    }
    
    public function getUsers()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        
        
        return $query->result();
        
        //return $query->result_array();
    }
    
    /* public function deleteUsers()
    {
        $this->db->where('id_usuario', 13);
        $this->db->delete('users');
    } */
}

?>
```

no se que es es lo que puede fallar. gracias

Comment: No des una intro en el título de la pregunta: _pon el error en cuestión_ (o descríbelo brevemente). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: No pongas imágenes de código, en su lugar aprende a formatearlo.  Fíjate como lo he puesto yo ahora (encerrado entre tres acentos graves al principio y al final para enmarcarlo como código)

Comment: Dices que no sabes lo que puede estar fallando, pero te has parado a leer el mensaje de error?  Te dice lo que falla (`Propiedad no definida`) y donde falla (linea 68). Coges, vas allí y podrás deducir mejor lo que te ocurre.

Comment: El fallo me lo da aqui en esta linea $data = $this->users_model->getUsers();

Comment: En este caso, esa línea pone `$data = $this->users_model->getUsers();`. Por lo tanto, puedes deducir que antes no has predefinido la instancia de objecto de la clase users_model en tu `__construct()` o en el `parent::__construct()` para que sea accesible a toda la clase

Comment: Lo he definido asi en el contructor                                                                   
                                                                                                                          
function __contruct()
 {
  parent:: __contruct();
  $this->load->model('users_model');
  
 }

Comment: Por cierto, en tu pregunta has puesto `$this->load->model('getAllUsers');` y no `$this->load->model('users_model');` como dices en los comentarios... quizas estás mirando otro archivo distinto al que has puesto aqui

Comment: Esta es la funcion para ver  todos los usuarios y es aqui donde me falla el programa                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                             
(public function getAllUsers()
 {
  $data = $this->users_model->getUsers();)

Comment: y diria que esto esta mal escrito tambien: `function __contruct()`  pues deberia ser `function __construct()`  (con **s**)

Comment: y consecuentemente, esto tambien estaria mal: `parent:: __contruct();`  pues deberia ser: `parent:: __construct();`  (con la **s**)... revisa todos los `__contruct` que tengas por ahi y ponlos bien

Comment: ok. ya me di cuenta

Comment: ya arregle ese error y ahora me sale esto                                                              
 Error de tecleado

Mensaje: Llamada al método no definido CI_Loader::getUsers()

Comment: function __construct()
 {
  parent:: __construct();
  $this->users_model = $this->load->model('users_model');
  
 }

Comment: no, no, he mirado la docu de codeigniter y eso te lo dije mal, perdona, por eso borré ese comentario.. déjalo así solo:  `$this->load->model('users_model'); `

Comment: a ver si con eso ya te funciona todo

Comment: ok. si ahora ya si muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según parece hay dos errores básicos, uno de tipeo y otro de concepto, y ambos estan en estas líneas:

```
function __contruct()
    {
        parent:: __contruct();
        $this->load->model('getAllUsers');
        
    }
```

donde `__contruct` aparece dos veces pero le falta una **s** en la palabra, pues debería ser `__construct`.

Y por el otro lado, parece que quiere ejecutar el método `getAllUsers` durante la construcción de la instancia de objeto de esa clase (`$this->load->model('getAllUsers');`), cuando seguramente lo que debería hacer es cargar el modelo `users_models`, lo cual debería ser así:

```
$this->load->model('users_model');
```

Con eso el error seguramente desaparezca, aunque pueden venir otros después, pero el que pregunta ya no.

Es decir, debería quedar así:

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->model('users_model');
        
    }
```

para que luego, cuando quieras ejecutar `getUsers()` simplemente creas una instancia de la clase y la llamas como a cualquier método, más o menos así:

```
$homeobj = new Home();
$homeobj->getAllUsers();
```